# Restful API in rails 3

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, restful-authentication

How should I go about creating a restful API in rails 3 app? Also I would like to know if there is a good way to implement restful authentication

Comment: If you need help creating json or xml response responses, I've written a blog post that will help: http://www.tmatthew.net/blog/rails_to_api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restful API in rails 3? Rails is restful.. just use routes [[guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)]

As for authentication, i strongly recommend [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). It's also the only one *I* have managed to get working on rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to authenticate applications that are using your API, checkout the the restful_api_authentication gem - https://rubygems.org/gems/restful_api_authentication

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create RESTful authentication in Rails is the combination of a User Model and a Session controller. So you will have new(login), create(authenticate), destroy(logout) actions in the Session controller. Depending on the app its fairly easy to write your own authentication. This screencast shows how easy it is. [Authentication in Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape)